# x201 tablet touch screen works like touchpad and not touch screen. stylus works however

Tags: touchscreen

When Ubuntu 12.04 starts on my X201T the touchscreen works fine, I can touch anywhere and the mouse will appear there. However once I log in to the desktop the touchscreen starts acting like a touchpad. if I touch the screen it acts like a permanent left click, and if I move my finger on the left side of the screen with the mouse on the right, it will follow my motions with a slightly larger motion, much like a touchpad on high sensitivity. Touching in random locations does not make the mouse appear (or jump to a new location like a miscalibrated screen).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your *touch* device works in *relative* mode. You need to switch it to the to *absolute* mode -- the same as your *stylus*. To do this try:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen touch" mode absolute
```

Note that your name of the device might be slightly different (this is from X200T). To list your devices run:

```
xsetwacom list
```